# How to execute "php artisan migrate" and other Laravel commands in remote server?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, remote-server

I'm using Laravel 4.2 in remote server and I want to execute Laravel commands `php artisan migrate` but I don't know how.

Comment: Is your remote server Linux? Do a web search for "server SSH tutorial", that should cover it. Check with your hosting provider that SSH access is provided. If not you might have to run these commands via a script, which is not ideal.

Comment: (Please note that questions this brief, and not featuring any evidence of prior research, will usually be closed here).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can ssh to the server and perform the command, you can add your servers public key to the remote server to do this without a password. I made a bash script with the following code which I can then execute manually via command line or from a program, lets say I call it myscript.sh with the following code

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 << EOF
cd /var/www/app/;
php artisan migrate --force; // force prevents artisan from asking for a yes/no on production
exit;
EOF
```

now I can write 'sh myscript.sh' and it will run migrations on the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to do this:

1. ssh into your server (for example, username root & server ip 1.1.1.1: `ssh root@1.1.1.1`).
2. go to your project folder (for example: `cd /var/....`)
3. run the command `php artisan migrate`.

---

**Original post (not the best way):**

You can setup a cronjob like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/app/artisan schedule:run
```

This will run every minute and run the migration.

You can change this to everything you want.

If you want to open a url what while be excecuting the command.

Use this code:

```
Artisan::call('migrate');
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Why would you use cronjob to run migrate every minute?

Comment: It's an example, he could also call another command like: `php artisan schedule:run`

Answer (score 0):

For the completeness of this article, you do this with Windows host using PS remote (enable first) then...

```
$Username   = "{domain}\{domain account}"
$PasswordSS = ConvertTo-SecureString '{domain account password}' -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred       = New-Object System.management.Automation.PSCredential $Username,$PasswordSS

Invoke-Command -ComputerName {server name} -ScriptBlock { cd d:\wwwroot\{website};php artisan migrate } -Credential $Cred
```

This will return the result to your local machine.

I use this in VSTS release deployments all the time.

Answer (score 0):

With Mac terminal

Step 1
sh root@your.ip.address e.g 181.6.41.221

Step 2
Enter your password

Step 3
cd /home/admin/web/yourdomain.com/public_html

Step 4 Laravel command:
"php artisan migrate"

Without the "quote"

Ask your host for your IP address and Password if not known by you.

Answer (score -4):

The solution to this problem could be running once a php code (on the server) like this:

```
<?php 
// installation.php file
echo exec('php /var/www/laravel-app/artisan migrate:install');
```

and than you need to visit `installation.php` in your browser.
After migration you should remove the installation file, so nobody can execute it again